# Ideal gas temperature and particle increase

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, ideal-gas

I fail to understand why an increase in the number of particles does not increase the temperature in case of ideal gas? Let's assume the increase mechanism  magically adds more particles of the same gas with the same average kinetic energy.

More particles create higher pressure -- there is more bumping into the walls:

$$
p={\frac {nRT}{V}}
$$

Gay-Lussac's law:

$$
P_{1}/T_{1}=P_{2}/T_{2}
$$

So if P2 = 2*P1 (due to more particles being added), T2 must also double, right?

I know similar question have been asked before (e.g. [Does increasing the pressure of the gas in a container by pumping gas into it increase temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/65254/does-increasing-the-pressure-of-the-gas-in-a-container-by-pumping-gas-into-it-in?rq=1)), but I would like to start a new discussion since those answers don't make it clear to me.

Comment: The laws that you cite describe what happens when you increase the pressure by _physical_ means. There's no reason those laws need to hold when the pressure increase is due to _magic._ (e.g., "...magically adds more particles...")

Comment: @SolomonSlow ok you don't like the word "magic", let's say it is a Maxwell's demon then, that keeps adding more particles.

Comment: Gay-Lussac’s law assumes constant mass (and volume) and can’t be applied here.

Comment: Maxwell's demon is equally magic. In fact, that was the whole point of the "demon" argument: It showed that if you could magically segregate low-energy particles from high-energy particles, then you could violate the laws of thermodynamics. But @Chemomechanics response is better than mine: It's not about "magic," It's about applying physical laws to situations that they were not intended to describe.

Comment: @SolomonSlow let's forget that we are dealing with the same volume. What if I have two same volume boxes A and B. A has half the amount of same gas particles than B. Which one will feel warmer?

Comment: @spacemonkey For open systems that can exchange heat and do work, we need three state variables for full characterization. You've specified the volume and mass. Now please select an additional variable (pressure, temperature, entropy, energy, or chemical potential) and compare it for the two systems. Then your question becomes answerable. This is equivalent to the previous answer that you linked that said the comparison is ambiguous until more path or state information is provided.